# What is use and purpose of read_text in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is the code

```
import pydoc
def read_float(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            number_text = read_text(prompt)
            result = float(number_text)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Enter a number')
    return result
read_float(1)
```

I am trying to use read_text function in python in this image[read_text program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed1Oc.png)

but the in terminal i am getting a error of read_text is not defined

Comment: `read_text()` isn't defined anywhere in the standard library, but you'll probably find it wherever you found the code you pasted.

Comment: Also please post the code instead of the image.

Comment: Thanks jedwards..i got it i have to define another function read_text in the current file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking at is not valid python code, unless `read_text()` is defined somewhere out of view. The function `read_text()` does not exist in standard python; rather, the built-in function `input()` serves that purpose instead. A proper implementation of that image you've provided is:

```
def read_float(prompt):                  # prompt is a string, e.g. "Enter a float"
    while True:                          # this is to continue trying if not-a-float is entered
        try:
            number_text = input(prompt)  # this prompts the user for input, and returns a string
            result = float(number_text)  # this tries to convert the string to a float
            break                        # exit this loop to return the float
        except ValueError:               # this is thrown by the previous line if number_text isn't able to be converted to a float
            print('Enter a Number')      # ask the user to try again
    return result
```

The result of running this function in my python console:

```
>>> read_float("Enter a float, please: ")
Enter a float, please: float
Enter a Number
Enter a float, please: 7.5
7.5
```